# Why template rendering get error for SVG element in ANgular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

```html
<html ng-app="vg">

  <body>
  
    <justsvg width="100" height="25"></justsvg>
    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('vg', []);
    app
.directive("justsvg", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope:{
            width: "@",
            height: "@"
        },
        template: "<svg width='{{width}}' height='{{height}}'></svg>"
    }
})
    
    </script>
    
    
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

ALl:

I am pretty new to Angular, when i try to render SVG in a directive, it keeps giving me error like:

```
<svg> attribute width: Expected length, "{{width}}".
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
.directive("justsvg", function(d3){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope:{
            width: "@",
            height: "@"
        },
        template: "<svg width='{{width}}' height='{{height}}'></svg>"
    }
})
```

The way I use it is:

```
<justsvg data=data width="100" height="25"></justsvg>
```

I wonder why even this simple usage still gets error? And also, could anyone show me how to debug this kinda error?

And interesting thing is: even I got this error, the SVG still can get rendered correctly

Comment: Try adding `ng-if="width && height"` to the directive's template, or see @Suren answer - I think they're correct

Comment: What happen when you add `ng-cloak` to the template? `"<div ng-cloak><svg width={{width}} height={{height}}></svg></div>"` ?

Comment: @AlonEitan Same error

Comment: This appears to be due to a browser implementation of SVG https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `=` to `@`.

`=` - **is a two-way binding. You must to pass a variable**
`@` - **is a one way binding. You pass a text to it.**

and put your width's and height's values into `'`.

**First Version**

You need to use `ng-width` and `ng-height`

```
template: "<svg ng-width='{{width}}' ng-height='{{height}}'></svg>"
```

**Second version**

```
.directive("justsvg", function(d3){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope:{
            data: "=",
            width: "@",
            height: "@"
        },
        template: "<svg></svg>",
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
                $element.attr('width', $scope.width);
                $element.attr('height', $scope.height);
        }
    }
})
```

And in the function you have a parameter with the name `d3`.If it is not an service you have defined, remove it.It also can make an error.

**For more see here:** https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

Comment: I did, it still shows:jquery.min.js:3 Error: <svg> attribute width: Expected length, "{{width}}" Error: <svg> attribute height: Expected length, "{{height}}".

Comment: Sorry, use them on where?

Comment: Yes, no more error now, thanks so much!  but what is wrong with that first version(cos if I have to use this way, that means I lost all template power)? Like I asked, if I meet this kinda error, how can I debug it?

Comment: Thanks, that is fine. Just keep u updated, when I add a <path d={{pathdata}}></path> in the template, this part get error too, it seems whatever attribute I added it will get error as long as it is a scope variable

Comment: Yes, that is right, I also mentioned this in my question, if I do not opern console, everything is fine, I just confuse about why I get this error and will this be a hidden bomb which could lead to future problem

Comment: Thanks, just quick question where did you find the whole set of ng attribute for SVG, is there every attr like ng-d ng-cx ng-x etcs?

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I get that. Just want to ask if there is whole set of directives for SVG. I am looking for a ng-d sorta thing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you didn't wrap {{}} with quotes, the template should be:

```
template: "<svg width='{{width}}' height='{{height}}'></svg>"
```